# Setting a TextView color to Color.Argb(255, 255, 255, 255); is not working for some reason on Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, colors, xamarin.android

I have multiple Text Views that I am displaying using an array adapter. I need the text views to follow a transparency gradient so the first textview has 255 alpha, the next one 255/2, then the next one 255/3 and then 0.

However, when I do the following, the textviews are completely transparent:

```
Color color = Color.Argb(255, 255, 255, 255);
rowYearTextView.SetTextColor(color);
```

I checked trough the debugger, and the color property of the text view on the first iteration of the array adapter is set to -1, which is correct as far as I understand. But for some reason, it won't display.

But if instead, I use a predefined color, then the textviews do show up. ex:

```
rowYearTextView.SetTextColor(Color.Aqua);
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Could it be a bug?

Comment: 255 is `FF` and that is 100% transparent, assuming you want `Color.Argb(0, 255, 255, 255)` for that first value.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks! That seemed to be the issue.